# Problems writing a query for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my SQL database:

```
mysql> select *from crop;
+------+-----------+----------+
| no   | name      | type     |
+------+-----------+----------+
| 1    | pineapple | fruits   |
| 2    | wheat     | mainFood |
| 1    | apple     | fruits   |
| 2    | corn      | main     |
| 3    | rose      | flower   |
| 2    | wheat     | main     |
| 2    | maize     | main     |
| 1    | drydates  | fruits   |
+------+-----------+----------+

mysql> select *from enviornment;
+---------+------------+----------+------+
| climate | irrigation | soil     | no   |
+---------+------------+----------+------+
| humid   | medium     | alluvial | 2    |
| humid   | medium     | black    | 1    |
| humid   | medium     | red      | 1    |
| sunny   | low        | black    | 1    |
| sunny   | medium     | alluvial | 1    |
| wet     | high       | red      | 2    |
| humid   | low        | red      | 3    |
+---------+------------+----------+------+
```

I want to get the `name` and `type` fields from the `crop table`, based on climate, soil, and irrigation.

I have written my query in the following way:

```
mysql> select T.name from((select name from crop)as T and (select no from envior
nment where climate like wet)as U)where T.no=U.no;
```

But when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and (select no from enviornment where climate like wet)as U)where T.no=U.no' at line 1

Can anyone tell me how to re-write my query to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **AND** to construct query-results, it's a [logical operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp). You can get all name, type, climate, soil and irrigation combinations with:

```
select c.name, c.type, e.climate, e.soil, e.irrigation
from crop c, environment e
where c.no = e.no;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select T.name 
from (select name from crop) as T 
inner join (select no from enviornment where climate like wet) as U
on T.no = U.no
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same without using subselects, which would be faster:

```
SELECT `T`.`name` 
FROM `enviornment` AS `U` 
    , `crop` AS `T`
WHERE `U`.`climate` LIKE 'wet'
    AND `U`.`no` = `T`.`no`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use comma between tables in the `from` clause, not `and`. You have forgotten the apostrophes around the string `'wet'`.

There is no point in selecting from subselects, you should just select from the tables directly:

```
select
  T.name, T.type
from
  crop as T,
  enviornment as U
where
  T.no = U.no and U.climate = 'wet'
```

Nowadays a join is commonly done using the `join` command:

```
select
  T.name, T.type
from
  crop as T,
  inner join enviornment as U on T.no = U.no
where
  U.climate = 'wet'
```

Note: Your table name `enviornment` is spelled wrong, it should be `environment`.

Answer (score 0):

user711934, although its nice having people show how to rewrite queries i suggest you do some more tutorials or buy a book etc on SQL queries specifically relating to joins to learn the fundamentals. 
You shouldn't rely on sub queries they are less efficient.

i suggest doing these tutorials
http://www.sql-tutorial.net/

specifically go through these join examples
http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-query-tuning.htm

I hope that helps